# Joining two List Elements one by one to make sublists inside a third list

Tags: python

I have two lists of equal length.

The first list consists of 1000 sublists with two elements each e.g

```
listone = [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3],...]
```

My second list consists of 1000 elements e.g.

```
secondlist = [1,2,3,...]
```

I want to use these two lists to make my third list consisting 1000 sublists of three elements. I want to have my list in such a fashion that every index is added from secondlist to listone as the third element e.g.

```
thirdlist = [[1,2,1], [1,3,2], [2,3,3],...]
```

Comment: Can you show any attempts that you've made so far?

Comment: `[sublist + [el] for sublist, el in zip(listone, secondlsit)]`.

Answer (score 4):

Look into `zip`:

```
listone = [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]
secondlist = [1,2,3]

thirdlist = [x + [y] for x, y in zip(listone, secondlist)]

print(thirdlist)

# Output:
# [[1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
[x + [y] for x, y in zip(listone, secondlist)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the zip function to combine `listOne` and `second`. To get the desired format you have to create a new list using `list comprehension`

```
listOne = [[1,2], [1,3], [2,3]]
secondList = [1,2,3]

thirdList = [x + [y] for x,y in zip(listOne, secondList)]
print thirdList
>>> [[1, 2, 1], [1, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3]]
```

Comment: Renaming `secondlist` to `third` is unnecessarily confusing. :-)

Comment: Ahmm i've kinda missed that comment, can you restate your changes? I can't find it :)

Comment: In your original code, you used `third` as the name of the second list. It's since been edited, but a reference to `third` can still be found in your first sentence. (You also have a typo there: should be "and" not "an.")

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciate it. Added the changes.

Comment: My only other feedback would be that it's strange that you renamed `listone` to `listOne`, etc. It's a little confusing for the person who asked the question, and Python naming conventions are to use snake_case, not camelCase. Of course, if you change those back to their original names, your answer will finally be an almost exact match of mine. :-)

Comment: :D I love SO! still my print statement and output formatting would stay different